# UIImagePickerController: is it possible to set overlay view only in editing mode after capture?

Tags: ios

I have AllowEditing set to true, and after the image is captured, I want to give additional instructions in the editing screen to crop out part of the image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerViewController` is in fact a `UINavigationController`. This gives you the ability to track on which step in the UINavigationViewController you are, so you can set the overlay view only when the second view controller is reached.

In brief:
- UIImagePickerController.delegate = self
- make self conform to the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol
- implement next method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController] == 1)
    {
        // If second UIViewController, set your overlay.
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work, since the editing mode is not a view controller in navigation controller, so this delegate will not call

Answer (score 0):

Dires De Smet, your solution is good, but not good enough, cause you don't really know for sure what is your current view controller's index (of curse you can find it, but its ugly)

So i come with new if condition, check it out:

Assuming self is your current UIViewController and not some NSObject subclass,
if self it is NSObject subclass, so use:

```
UIViewController *currentViewController=(UIViewController *)[[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController]navigationController]viewControllers]lastObject];
```

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (![viewController isKindOfClass:[self class]]){
        //do your thing...
    }
}
```